# VPN Split Tunneling on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, vpn

I use uTorrent and other programs to download from the internet and use chrome for browsing

how can I make chrome only use the vpn while the other programs use the direct line ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you probably cannot.

Routing works by IP addresses, not by ports and programs. If you knew that one program would try to go to only certain IP addresses, and another would try to go to other IP addresses, you could change your routing tables, but I can't see that happening in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`VPN` tunnels **all** traffic within a single connection. Therefore, you cannot choose which application to exclude from VPN.

Try using HTTP/Web proxies instead, for example [from here](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/).